# How to include user defined index into table of contents

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

I inserted a user defined index in my LibreOffice Writer document. How can I include (the heading of) this into my table of contents?

I tried `Insert` > `Index & Tables` > `Entry`, but the heading of the user defined index cannot be selected as an entry (to include in table of contents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Table of Contents (ToC) entry for the alphabetical index the following way:

1. If you already have inserted a Table of Contents, right-click on it and select "`Edit Index/Table`"; otherwise, put the cursor at the place where the ToC should appear, and select Menu "`Insert`" -> "`Indexes and Tables...`" -> "`Indexes and Tables...`", and select Type = "`Table of Contents`". Now, you should see the following window:

   [image]
2. Enable the "`Additional Styles`" option (see screenshot above), and click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button next to the right. Now, the following window should appear:

   [image]
3. Here, you see a list of styles and a table with the heading levels 1 to 10. LibreOffice will ignore all styles in the leftmost column ("`Not applied`") when creating the ToC. By default, the index heading is ignored, too. To let LO recognize that style, select the entry "`Index heading`" in the Styles list, and move it to the right, using the arrow buttons <kbd><<</kbd> / <kbd>>></kbd>:

   [image]

   The columns `1` to `10` symbolize the heading level where the index heading should appear in the ToC: if you want the "`Alphabetical Index`" entry appear on the same level as `Heading 1` headings, move it to the "`1`" column; if `Heading 2`, then `column 2` and so on. So, to make LO recognize the "`Alphabetical Index`" ToC entry as `Heading 1` heading, the window should look like this:

   [image]
4. Now, just click <kbd>OK</kbd> and create the ToC. It will contain an entry for the Alphabetical Index on the level you've specified above.